# How to Reset The Firewall rules on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

1. how can we list all existing rules?
2. how to reset all unwanted firewall rules?
3. please mentioned list of **commands**.

Answer (score 0):

below commands are useful to do that

To list the rules

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

to delete rule

```
sudo ufw delete <rule no from above command results>
```

After deleting all rules execute below lined command

```
sudo ufw --force disable \
&& sudo ufw --force reset \
&& sudo ufw default deny incoming \
&& sudo ufw default allow outgoing \
&& sudo ufw allow 22/tcp \
&& sudo ufw allow 80/tcp \
&& sudo ufw allow 443/tcp \
&& sudo ufw --force enable
```